# The name of popup window onclick of an Android app

Tags: java, android, user-interface, frontend

I would like to know what is the name of a UI component: it’s like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETeZ7.jpg) in the CITIZEN app , when we click on the pin on the map, a small card would pop up in the same activity (the users are not led to the other activity but remain in the same one).

I would like to know what this “small card” is professionally called in UI, so that I can google how to implement it in my Android app.

Comment: maybe android bottom sheet ? https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-bottom-sheet-7e9cfcec6427

Comment: There's really no way to know for sure unless you have the source code (or can reverse engineer) the actual app.  Frankly, it might not even be a "native Android" app.  Neverthess: it looks similar to an Android [toast](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts), in that it "pops up" (like bread in a toaster).  Angel Koh suggested it might be a [Bottom Sheet](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/package-summary).  Or it might be something else entirely...

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it looks like a custom 'snackbar'.
You should be able to google that.

Comment: "Snackbar in android is a new widget introduced with the Material Design library as a replacement of a Toast": https://www.journaldev.com/10324/android-snackbar-example-tutorial  See also: https://developer.android.com/training/snackbar/showing